# waitForIt Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone want to comment on this plugin I'm making? (improvements, etc)

```
(function($) {

    var methods = {
        init: function(data) {

            var options = {
                function: null,
                timeout: 1000,
                option: undefined
            }

            return this.each(function() {
                var self = $(this);
                $.extend(options, data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self[options.function].apply(self, [options.options]);
                }, options.timeOut)
            })
        }

    }

    $.fn.waitForit = function(method) {
        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.waitForit');
        }

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Ad3pv/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery already has this functionality. Multiple animations on an element already automatically queue and wait until the previous animation has run. If you want to have a pause between two animations you can use `.delay()`.

For example:

```
$('div.B').show('blind').delay(1000).fadeOut().delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
```

will do what your example with the plugin does (timing may needed to be adjusted a bit).

Also animation methods call take a callback function as an argument, which will be called, when that specific animation is finished.

Comment: yes, but i made this for a user whose `delay()` was not working

Comment: Then it would be better to find out *why* `delay()` isn't working. Most likely because`delay()` is only for animations and he's using it with non-animation methods. If he's using it with AJAX methods he should be using callbacks and `setTimeout` instead, or look into the new Deferred functionality of jQuery 1.5. And if that doesn't work, then post an example of the non-working code on Stack Overflow (not here).

Comment: @RoTada. lol thats why i gave this solution. it uses `setTimeout` and the like, it is basically a `delay` but for non animations

Comment: But your solution is more complex and inflexible (only one argument possible), than directly using built-in callbacks.